# Handle tap on map and annotaions

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

Im use UIViewRepresentable map in SwiftUI and I need handle taps on map and on annotation as two different actions. I use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to handle taps on map to get coordinates and use mapView didSelect MKAnnotationView to handle taps on annotation. Problem is when tapped annotation - UITapGestureRecognizer triggered too.

```
final class MapCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    var parent: UIkitMapView
    var gRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    
    init(_ parent: UIkitMapView) {
        self.parent = parent
        super.init()
        self.gRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler))
        self.gRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.parent.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gRecognizer)
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        print(view.annotation?.title)
        parent.showPlaceDetails = true
      }
    
    @objc func tapHandler(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gRecognizer.location(in: self.parent.mapView)
        let coordinate = self.parent.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.parent.mapView)
        let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
        pin.coordinate = coordinate
        parent.setPinOnMap(point: pin)
        print("new pin")
    }
}
```